# how to send mail on specified date and time using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, email, automation

**what I have is,**

1. user specified date and time in the database.
2. a php script to send mail.

**Required**

1. trigger php script when specified date and time arrives.

I am using local apache server

Example: A wants to send mail to B in 5 days from now. A enters date and time in database and after 5 days it will automatically sent by running php mailer script.

Is there any way of scheduling this?

Comment: make 1 cron job and schedule it. At the time of entering date and time in db also add send date and time so that in cron specify the condition that on the send date and time run the cron and send the email.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to get the sender and receiver list from DB for executing date.

```
ex:  check php date is equal to DB date to sent the email.
Add the php script to a cron job
```

Check the sample code

```
$queryToGetuserListToSendEmail = "select * from userlist where date_toSend_email = ''". date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'";
$userListToSendEmail = array();//senders relievers and other details taken from DB to send emails

foreach ($userListToSendEmail as $usersToSendEmail){
//sendEmail
}
```

Cron job for running the job every day 2.30 A.M (add this in your cron tab)

```
30 2 * * * php /pathtoyourfile
```

Comment: can you provide a sample code for adding php script to cron job by extracting date from DB

Answer (score 0):

you can use script for check diff date now by date in database for interval 1 min or 1 second or ever time run script check .for example by php :

```
public static function diff_time($date, $timezone = null,$now=null)
    {
        if($now == null)
        {
            $now =  date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $now = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $time_now = time();
        }
        if(is_int($date)){
            $time = $date;
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
        }
        else{
            $time = strtotime($date);
        }
        $date=new \DateTime($date);
        $diff=$date->diff($now);
        return $diff`;}
```

you can use check diff time if near or zero time  send mail.
now you can add

```
crontab -e
```

add

```
` * * * * * php ~/script.php`
```

by in example run every time check and send mail